# How to get the secondary id of the view in RCP framework

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am new to Eclipse RCP framework.

I have created multiple instances of the same view by appending secondary id in the primary id of the view using following code:

```java
folderLayout1.addPlaceholder(DiagramWindow.ID + ":*");

IWorkbenchPage activePage = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
activePage.showView(DiagramWindow.ID, Integer.toString(DiagramList.viewIndex++),
IWorkbenchPage.VIEW_ACTIVATE);
```

Now when I try to get the id of the active view, then I get only the primary id of the view. I did not find any way to get the secondary id of the view. Due to this I always get the reference of the last opened view in the folderLayout.

Please provide some solution. I am stuck in this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say where in your code you want the secondary id.

If you have a `IViewReference` for the view call the `IViewReference.getSecondaryId()` method.

If you have a `IViewPart` call

```java
viewPart.getViewSite().getSecondaryId()
```